# NavigationBar without statusbar overlaps safearea in iOS11

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11, safearealayoutguide

I have a problem in iOS11 with the iPhoneX simulator.

I have a viewcontroller without the statusbar. To do this I add:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

It is good so far but the navigationbar overlaps the safearea in the iPhoneX.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: is your navigation bar a standard UINavigationBar, or a custom solution?

Comment: My navigationbar is standar @CalStephens

Comment: Hi, my full-screen app uses navigation controllers too and I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @FernandoReynoso Yes I solved this. I'm gonna write the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally the solution was using `safeAreaInsets`

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        UIEdgeInsets safeInsets = UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.safeAreaInsets;
        paddingTop = safeInsets.top;
}
```

You can do this programatically or using autolayout

[image]  [image]