# UINavigationBar overlapping status bar when open project in xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13

I am facing a strange issue right now, I have developed an app which contain `UITabBar` and inside `tabBarController` there are 5 tabs when I run the application in Xcode 11 gm seed version. After login successfully I load the tabbar. By default its load the tab at index 0.At index 0 navigation bar load perfectly fine without the overlapping status bar. but when I move to the other tabs then `navigationbar` get disturb with the overlapping status bar,I don't know how to deal with this issue, but 1 think I realize that when I switch the tabs on the storyboard when every time when it loads the first time its navigation display perfectly fine. but for other tabs `navigationbar` get disturbed.

Comment: Is this issue is only seen in xcode 11?

Comment: @AmritTiwari yes bro . its happen to me only in xcode 11 gm seed version

Answer (score 1):

Did you try by using Safe area?

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        UIEdgeInsets safeInsets = UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.safeAreaInsets;
        paddingTop = safeInsets.top;
}
```

Look at this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723732/3887987) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix this issue just by commenting transition code after login

```
 //   UIView.transition(from: appDelegate.window.rootViewController!.view, to: tabbarObj.view, duration: 0.65, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight) { (finished) -> Void in
            appDelegate.window.rootViewController = tabbarObj;
      //  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fix the issue in Xamarin adding this line `Window.rootViewController = navBar` into the below method in the `ViewPresenter` class.

```
protected override UINavigationController CreateNavigationController(UIViewController viewController)
        {
            var navBar = base.CreateNavigationController(viewController);
            navBar.NavigationBarHidden = true;

            Window.RootViewController = navBar;
            return navBar;
        }
```

Comment: who cares about Xamarin? question is tagged with `xcode`

Comment: The platform doesn't matter. The solution is assigning navigationBar to rootViewController.

Comment: if the platform doesn't matter, then why mention it in the first place? Extra confusion is not helpful.